# MySQL : sum per group and overall

Tags: mysql

for a project I have a query where I aggregate data:

```
SELECT
    code,
    SUM(someValue) as summedValueForCode
FROM
    someTable
GROUP BY
    code;
```

Now, what I need is a third column that defines the % the summedValueForCode represents over all rows. So summedValueForCode / summedValueForAllRows.

I could do something like:

```
SELECT
    code,
    SUM(someValue) as summedValueForCode,
    (100 * SUM(someValue) / (SELECT sum(someValue) FROM someTable)) as valueForCodeToTotal
FROM
    someTable
GROUP BY
    code;
```

But it doesn't look very elegant.

Another option would be:

```
SELECT
    code,
    SUM(someValue) as summedValueForCode,
    (100 * SUM(someValue) / totalSum) as valueForCodeToTotal
FROM
    someTable,
    (SELECT sum(someValue) as totalSum FROM someTable) as summedTable
GROUP BY
    code;
```

But still, since the real query is quite complex, I don't like the idea of adding the query like that a second time.

Is there a way using aggregate function to calculate the SUM over all rows ignoring the GROUP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THere is no such analytical function in MySQL.
You will have to help yourself with the subquery.

You could write a UDF that helps you with that problem, but that is even more complex. You would have to do some C/C++ programming.

Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html

Do not try to implement a function in MySQL directly. It will be slow as hell. If you create a function, it must be a UDF plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is! (if I literally answer to the question in the last row)

```
SELECT
    code,
    SUM(someValue) as summedValueForCode
FROM
    someTable
GROUP BY
    code
WITH ROLLUP # here is where the magic happens
```

you'll get something like this as output

```
code - summedValueForCode
  A      100
  B      200
  C       50
null     350
```

Filter the code for null and you'll get the total you're looking for.

Be warned, the use of WITH ROLLUP has some restrictions, which you can look for in the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: I know about ROLLUP, but it is only okay to have it at the end of your rows... not to use it within the 3 rows A, B, C in your example. thanks for taking the time to answer though, much appreciated!